# What techniques are there to create a geometric diamond pattern in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, patterns

I cannot figure out how to go about making a pattern similar to this one:

[image: http://payload146.cargocollective.com/1/0/333/5222009/b3.png]

I know it must be relatively simple but I cannot wrap my mind around creating a consistent repeating pattern. 
thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd start by use the brush to scribble with some different colors that you'd like.

[image: Everyone Likes Scribbling]

Then we can use **Filter** → **Pixelate** → **Mosaic...** to turn it into some nice squares

[image: It is hip to square things]

Then we can do a ***Skew*** transform (<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> on Windows)

[image: Skew you]

Tweak and crop as necessary to get the size and angle you want

Comment: okay I thought you were mocking me when I saw your first pic but this is brilliant thanks!!

Comment: I agree. This is brilliant. And ridiculously easy to boot.

Comment: That's pretty much how I'd do it. Try a couple of other filters and create some actions. It gets pretty sick how easy you can generate some patterns. I just wish there was a way to do the random brush stroke issue. Note: the colors you use don't have to be precise. Just use Hue Saturation or color shift options to change to the tone you want. Just get the contrasts correct and blend til you see the correct colors.